# Informação incorreta ao carregar entidade bigdecimal

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, persistência

Eu tenho uma tabela, que uma de suas colunas é um **numeric(25,10)** que será mostrado as taxas. Mas existe registros que serão zerados ( 0.0000000000 )

Na minha entidade tem a propriedade dessa taxa, como um **BigDecimal**. Mas quando o **hibernate** popula essa propriedade ele atribui o valor **"0E-10"** inves de 0.0000000000. Eu já tentei colocar *precision* ou *Scale*, mas não encontrei a solução.

```
@DecimalMin("0.0")
@Digits(integer = 25, fraction = 10)
@Field(at = 8, required = true)
@Column(name = TableConstants.Columns.TAXA_OPERACAO)
private BigDecimal taxaOperacao;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu tentei isso também @BrunoCésar, mas continua retornando o "EO-10"

Comment: Se eu tento pegar essa propriedade BigDecimal, e chamar o seu método toPlainString(), ele retorna o valor corretamente.

Comment: Isso não está incorreto @DaniloFernandes. Está ocorrendo que  o BigDecimal está sendo representado na notação científica. Note que 0E-10 = 0x(10^(-10)) = 0/(10^10) = 0. Na sua pergunta está escrito incorreto, está EO-10, enquanto no seu debug está 0E-10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não existe nada incorreto. Ocorre que o 0.0000000000 está sendo representado pela notação científica quando visualizado pelo debug.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Enfim, isso não vai causar nenhum erro, já que é apenas uma representação. Suas contas serão feitas com 0.

**UPDATE** - Complementado a resposta:

Fiquei curioso com o fato de que pra alguns casos o toString() do BigDecimal imprime na notação científica, pra outros casos não. Verifiquei no código fonte e, como pode ser observado no trecho de código abaixo, a decisão é feita baseado no número armazenado.

O método abaixo, layoutChars, é chamado pelo **toString()** passando **true** para o parametro **sci**. O parametro **sci** significa imprimir na notação científica. Se ele for falso, então o número é impresso na notação de engenharia.

Note que depende de algumas condições para que o número seja impresso na notação científica, sendo a variável **scale**, **adjusted** e o parametro **sci** responsáveis por isso.

```
3051  private String layoutChars(boolean sci) {
3052      if (scale == 0)                      // zero scale is trivial
3053          return (intCompact != INFLATED) ?
3054              Long.toString(intCompact):
3055              intVal.toString();
3057      // Get the significand as an absolute value
3058      char coeff[];
3059      if (intCompact != INFLATED)
3060          coeff = Long.toString(Math.abs(intCompact)).toCharArray();
3061      else
3062          coeff = intVal.abs().toString().toCharArray();
3064      // Construct a buffer, with sufficient capacity for all cases.
3065      // If E-notation is needed, length will be: +1 if negative, +1
3066      // if '.' needed, +2 for "E+", + up to 10 for adjusted exponent.
3067      // Otherwise it could have +1 if negative, plus leading "0.00000"
3068      StringBuilder buf=new StringBuilder(coeff.length+14);
3069      if (signum() < 0)             // prefix '-' if negative
3070          buf.append('-');
3071      long adjusted = -(long)scale + (coeff.length-1);
3072      if ((scale >= 0) && (adjusted >= -6)) { // plain number
3073          int pad = scale - coeff.length;  // count of padding zeros
3074          if (pad >= 0) {                  // 0.xxx form
3075              buf.append('0');
3076              buf.append('.');
3077              for (; pad>0; pad--) {
3078                  buf.append('0');
3079              }
3080              buf.append(coeff);
3081          } else {                         // xx.xx form
3082              buf.append(coeff, 0, -pad);
3083              buf.append('.');
3084              buf.append(coeff, -pad, scale);
3085          }
3086      } else { // E-notation is needed
3087          if (sci) {                       // Scientific notation
3088              buf.append(coeff[0]);        // first character
3089              if (coeff.length > 1) {      // more to come
3090                  buf.append('.');
3091                  buf.append(coeff, 1, coeff.length-1);
3092              }
3093          } else {                         // Engineering notation
3094              int sig = (int)(adjusted % 3);
3095              if (sig < 0)
3096                  sig += 3;                // [adjusted was negative]
3097              adjusted -= sig;             // now a multiple of 3
3098              sig++;
3099              if (signum() == 0) {
3100                  switch (sig) {
3101                  case 1:
3102                      buf.append('0'); // exponent is a multiple of three
3103                      break;
3104                  case 2:
3105                      buf.append("0.00");
3106                      adjusted += 3;
3107                      break;
3108                  case 3:
3109                      buf.append("0.0");
3110                      adjusted += 3;
3111                      break;
3112                  default:
3113                      throw new AssertionError("Unexpected sig value " + sig);
3114                  }
3115              } else if (sig >= coeff.length) {   // significand all in integer
3116                  buf.append(coeff, 0, coeff.length);
3117                  // may need some zeros, too
3118                  for (int i = sig - coeff.length; i > 0; i--)
3119                      buf.append('0');
3120              } else {                     // xx.xxE form
3121                  buf.append(coeff, 0, sig);
3122                  buf.append('.');
3123                  buf.append(coeff, sig, coeff.length-sig);
3124              }
3125          }
3126          if (adjusted != 0) {             // [!sci could have made 0]
3127              buf.append('E');
3128              if (adjusted > 0)            // force sign for positive
3129                  buf.append('+');
3130              buf.append(adjusted);
3131          }
3132      }
3133      return buf.toString();
3134  }
```

Por fim, o debug do Java, mostrado na imagem da pergunta está chamando o toString() e o número armazenado, 0.0000000000, faz com que a impressão seja na notação científica.

Este trecho de código foi extraído de: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigDecimal.java#BigDecimal.toString%28%29